# I am trying to fit an exponential function to my graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, exponential, model-fitting

In R, I have a large dataframe of 1000 simulations with an exponential distribution.

When I use gg_plot I get a graph which looks like this:
[image: A graph showing the resulting prevalence over time for 1000 simulations]

I am trying to estimate the values for the exponential function for this graph and then plot a line using those values.

I am quite new to stack-overflow. Returning to the graph, I have first converted the y and x values (q and t respectively) to logarithmic form and performed a linear regression. That looks like this:

```
surscript$logq<-log(surscript$q)
surscript$logt<-log(surscript$t)
linearmod<-lm(surscript$logq~surscript$logt)
```

That gave me a y intercept at -14.273, and a growth rate of 1.717.
To convert that back to exponential I performed a exponential function on these values.

```
expmodint<-exp(-14.273)
expmodgrowth<-exp(1.717)
```

I then used the exponential equation, y=a*e^t, to describe a q value:

```
temp<-expmodint*(expmodgrowth^surscript$t)
```

I then created a dataframe containing this exponential equation and the t from the original dataframe:

```
 temp1<-data.frame(temp,surscript$t)
```

I then tried to add this line to my existing graph as seen above by using geom_line:

```
p+geom_line(temp1,aes(x=temp,y=surscript$t))
```

However I am returning the error "mapping must be created by "aes"".

Could anyone advice on why this error is occurring, and possibly a better way of calculating and fitting the exponential curve?

**EDIT:** Here I include the dataframe for two simulations, therefore, you will be able to work with some data.

```
structure(list(sim = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("simulation 1", 
"simulation 2"), class = "factor"), m = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), q = c(0.001, 
0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.005, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.011, 0.016, 
0.02, 0.026, 0.033, 0.035, 0.041, 0.045, 0.05, 0.052, 0.054, 
0.058, 0.064, 0.066, 0.071, 0.075, 0.08, 0.087, 0.097, 0.111, 
0.124, 0.132, 0.143, 0.154, 0.162, 0.176, 0.188, 0.205, 0.216, 
0.225, 0.231, 0.241, 0.252, 0.269, 0.287, 0.301, 0.32, 0.345, 
0.358, 0.383, 0.406, 0.429, 0.454, 0.479, 0.493, 0.521, 0.541, 
0.565, 0.587, 0.606, 0.635, 0.654, 0.677, 0.694, 0.712, 0.729, 
0.744, 0.766, 0.783, 0.805, 0.815, 0.824, 0.835, 0.849, 0.859, 
0.866, 0.881, 0.888, 0.9, 0.912, 0.92, 0.925, 0.934, 0.941, 0.944, 
0.949, 0.954, 0.959, 0.963, 0.965, 0.97, 0.974, 0.977, 0.978, 
0.98, 0.981, 0.984, 0.986, 0.987, 0.988, 0.989, 0.989, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.991, 0.992, 0.992, 0.992, 0.992, 0.993, 0.995, 
0.996, 0.997, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 
0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 
0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 1, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 
0.003, 0.005, 0.007, 0.011, 0.016, 0.022, 0.026, 0.028, 0.031, 
0.036, 0.043, 0.044, 0.051, 0.056, 0.059, 0.064, 0.072, 0.076, 
0.083, 0.083, 0.088, 0.096, 0.099, 0.103, 0.111, 0.118, 0.125, 
0.129, 0.139, 0.145, 0.148, 0.156, 0.166, 0.175, 0.184, 0.191, 
0.197, 0.2, 0.207, 0.211, 0.219, 0.224, 0.238, 0.25, 0.265, 0.273, 
0.289, 0.3, 0.313, 0.328, 0.344, 0.354, 0.368, 0.378, 0.387, 
0.399, 0.411, 0.424, 0.439, 0.455, 0.468, 0.48, 0.497, 0.503, 
0.513, 0.52, 0.53, 0.539, 0.552, 0.56, 0.569, 0.581, 0.588, 0.596, 
0.604, 0.618, 0.626, 0.64, 0.654, 0.672, 0.688, 0.705, 0.723, 
0.733, 0.747, 0.765, 0.781, 0.795, 0.807, 0.818, 0.825, 0.836, 
0.843, 0.854, 0.863, 0.872, 0.875, 0.883, 0.889, 0.901, 0.906, 
0.914, 0.92, 0.928, 0.936, 0.943, 0.953, 0.958, 0.96, 0.965, 
0.967, 0.968, 0.97, 0.973, 0.975, 0.979, 0.981, 0.982, 0.984, 
0.984, 0.988, 0.99, 0.99, 0.992, 0.992, 0.992, 0.994, 0.994, 
0.994, 0.995, 0.996, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 0.998, 
0.998, 0.998, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 
0.999, 0.999, 0.999, 1), t = c(21, 51, 81, 111, 141, 171, 201, 
231, 261, 291, 321, 351, 381, 411, 441, 471, 501, 531, 561, 591, 
621, 651, 681, 711, 741, 771, 801, 831, 861, 891, 921, 951, 981, 
1011, 1041, 1071, 1101, 1131, 1161, 1191, 1221, 1251, 1281, 1311, 
1341, 1371, 1401, 1431, 1461, 1491, 1521, 1551, 1581, 1611, 1641, 
1671, 1701, 1731, 1761, 1791, 1821, 1851, 1881, 1911, 1941, 1971, 
2001, 2031, 2061, 2091, 2121, 2151, 2181, 2211, 2241, 2271, 2301, 
2331, 2361, 2391, 2421, 2451, 2481, 2511, 2541, 2571, 2601, 2631, 
2661, 2691, 2721, 2751, 2781, 2811, 2841, 2871, 2901, 2931, 2961, 
2991, 3021, 3051, 3081, 3111, 3141, 3171, 3201, 3231, 3261, 3291, 
3321, 3351, 3381, 3411, 3441, 3471, 3501, 3531, 3561, 3591, 3621, 
3651, 3681, 3711, 3741, 3771, 3801, 3831, 3861, 3891, 3921, 3951, 
3981, 4011, 4041, 4071, 4, 34, 64, 94, 124, 154, 184, 214, 244, 
274, 304, 334, 364, 394, 424, 454, 484, 514, 544, 574, 604, 634, 
664, 694, 724, 754, 784, 814, 844, 874, 904, 934, 964, 994, 1024, 
1054, 1084, 1114, 1144, 1174, 1204, 1234, 1264, 1294, 1324, 1354, 
1384, 1414, 1444, 1474, 1504, 1534, 1564, 1594, 1624, 1654, 1684, 
1714, 1744, 1774, 1804, 1834, 1864, 1894, 1924, 1954, 1984, 2014, 
2044, 2074, 2104, 2134, 2164, 2194, 2224, 2254, 2284, 2314, 2344, 
2374, 2404, 2434, 2464, 2494, 2524, 2554, 2584, 2614, 2644, 2674, 
2704, 2734, 2764, 2794, 2824, 2854, 2884, 2914, 2944, 2974, 3004, 
3034, 3064, 3094, 3124, 3154, 3184, 3214, 3244, 3274, 3304, 3334, 
3364, 3394, 3424, 3454, 3484, 3514, 3544, 3574, 3604, 3634, 3664, 
3694, 3724, 3754, 3784, 3814, 3844, 3874, 3904, 3934, 3964, 3994, 
4024, 4054, 4084, 4114, 4144, 4174, 4204, 4234, 4264, 4294, 4324, 
4354, 4384, 4414, 4444, 4474, 4504, 4534, 4564), n = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), logq = c(-6.90775527898214, 
-6.90775527898214, -6.21460809842219, -6.21460809842219, -5.29831736654804, 
-5.29831736654804, -5.11599580975408, -4.96184512992682, -4.50986000618377, 
-4.13516655674236, -3.91202300542815, -3.64965874096066, -3.41124771751566, 
-3.35240721749272, -3.19418321227783, -3.10109278921182, -2.99573227355399, 
-2.95651156040071, -2.91877123241786, -2.84731226843572, -2.74887219562247, 
-2.71810053695571, -2.64507540194082, -2.59026716544583, -2.52572864430826, 
-2.44184716032755, -2.33304430047875, -2.1982250776698, -2.0874737133771, 
-2.02495335639577, -1.94491064872223, -1.87080267656851, -1.82015894374975, 
-1.73727128394399, -1.67131331615219, -1.58474529984373, -1.53247687129797, 
-1.49165487677772, -1.46533756846034, -1.42295834549148, -1.37832619147071, 
-1.3130438993803, -1.24827306322252, -1.20064501423326, -1.13943428318836, 
-1.06421086195078, -1.02722229258144, -0.959720289801491, -0.901402119380404, 
-0.84629836005412, -0.789658080940789, -0.736054681571222, -0.707246104939447, 
-0.65200523722877, -0.614336000135655, -0.570929547835696, -0.532730459154041, 
-0.500875292912823, -0.454130280089445, -0.424647927524938, -0.390084006069862, 
-0.365283318475333, -0.339677367570161, -0.316081546973479, -0.295714244149045, 
-0.266573109241546, -0.244622582991334, -0.216913001563574, -0.204567165741274, 
-0.193584749072665, -0.180323554131282, -0.16369609267079, -0.151986356997882, 
-0.143870370419702, -0.126697653045958, -0.118783535989967, -0.105360515657826, 
-0.0921152889078056, -0.083381608939051, -0.0779615414697118, 
-0.0682788407532944, -0.0608121393967575, -0.0576291128366364, 
-0.0523464803722092, -0.0470916075338506, -0.0418642040986989, 
-0.0377018671840115, -0.0356271776431512, -0.0304592074847086, 
-0.026343975339602, -0.0232686269393543, -0.0222456089473197, 
-0.0202027073175195, -0.019182819416774, -0.0161293819298836, 
-0.0140989243795016, -0.0130852395486555, -0.0120725812342692, 
-0.0110609473594249, -0.0110609473594249, -0.0100503358535015, 
-0.0100503358535015, -0.0100503358535015, -0.0100503358535015, 
-0.00904074465214907, -0.00803217169726427, -0.00803217169726427, 
-0.00803217169726427, -0.00803217169726427, -0.00702461493696447, 
-0.00501254182354429, -0.00400802139753882, -0.00300450902029872, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 
-0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 
-0.00100050033358353, 0, -6.90775527898214, -6.21460809842219, 
-5.80914299031403, -5.80914299031403, -5.29831736654804, -4.96184512992682, 
-4.50986000618377, -4.13516655674236, -3.81671282562382, -3.64965874096066, 
-3.57555076880693, -3.47376807449699, -3.32423634052603, -3.14655516328857, 
-3.12356564506388, -2.97592964625781, -2.88240358824699, -2.83021783507642, 
-2.74887219562247, -2.63108915996608, -2.57702193869581, -2.48891467118554, 
-2.48891467118554, -2.43041846450393, -2.3434070875143, -2.31263542884755, 
-2.2730262907525, -2.1982250776698, -2.13707065451647, -2.07944154167984, 
-2.04794287462046, -1.97328134585145, -1.93102153656156, -1.91054300521802, 
-1.8578992717326, -1.79576749062559, -1.74296930505862, -1.69281952137315, 
-1.65548185093551, -1.62455155024415, -1.6094379124341, -1.57503648571677, 
-1.55589714550607, -1.51868354916564, -1.4961092271271, -1.43548460531066, 
-1.38629436111989, -1.32802545299591, -1.29828348379718, -1.2413285908697, 
-1.20397280432594, -1.16155208844198, -1.11474167059799, -1.06711362160874, 
-1.03845836584836, -0.999672340813206, -0.972861083362549, -0.949330585952355, 
-0.918793862092274, -0.889162064485903, -0.858021823750179, -0.823255865906966, 
-0.787457860031187, -0.75928698306449, -0.7339691750802, -0.699165252885508, 
-0.687165108882398, -0.667479433811368, -0.653926467406664, -0.63487827243597, 
-0.61803970807314, -0.594207232705042, -0.579818495252942, -0.563874844855806, 
-0.543004522130226, -0.53102833108351, -0.517514611916787, -0.504181081047322, 
-0.481266821524446, -0.468404907882039, -0.446287102628419, -0.424647927524938, 
-0.397496938458987, -0.373966441048793, -0.349557476169868, -0.324346056823372, 
-0.310609577095486, -0.29169009384932, -0.267879445155601, -0.247180129142451, 
-0.229413164327805, -0.214431610712188, -0.20089294237939, -0.192371892647456, 
-0.179126665897435, -0.170788320980282, -0.157824085193567, -0.147340587898709, 
-0.136965855073157, -0.133531392624523, -0.124430078378177, -0.117658043468232, 
-0.104250021373799, -0.0987159729391577, -0.089924707527987, 
-0.083381608939051, -0.0747235461959364, -0.0661398025045449, 
-0.0586889963486796, -0.048140375327935, -0.0429075010112765, 
-0.0408219945202552, -0.0356271776431512, -0.0335567835288428, 
-0.0325231917055601, -0.0304592074847086, -0.027371196796132, 
-0.0253178079842899, -0.0212236364516267, -0.019182819416774, 
-0.0181639706276712, -0.0161293819298836, -0.0161293819298836, 
-0.0120725812342692, -0.0100503358535015, -0.0100503358535015, 
-0.00803217169726427, -0.00803217169726427, -0.00803217169726427, 
-0.00601807232556302, -0.00601807232556302, -0.00601807232556302, 
-0.00501254182354429, -0.00400802139753882, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, -0.00200200267067308, 
-0.00200200267067308, -0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 
-0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 
-0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 
-0.00100050033358353, -0.00100050033358353, 0), logt = c(3.04452243772342, 
3.93182563272433, 4.39444915467244, 4.70953020131233, 4.94875989037817, 
5.14166355650266, 5.30330490805908, 5.44241771052179, 5.56452040732269, 
5.67332326717149, 5.77144112313002, 5.86078622346587, 5.9427993751267, 
6.01859321449623, 6.08904487544685, 6.15485809401642, 6.21660610108486, 
6.27476202124194, 6.3297209055227, 6.3818160174061, 6.43133108193348, 
6.47850964220857, 6.52356230614951, 6.56667242980324, 6.60800062529609, 
6.64768837356333, 6.68586094706836, 6.72262979485545, 6.75809450442773, 
6.79234442747081, 6.82546003625531, 6.85751406254539, 6.88857245956536, 
6.91869521902047, 6.94793706861497, 6.97634807044775, 7.00397413672268, 
7.03085747611612, 7.05703698169789, 7.0825485693553, 7.1074254741107, 
7.13169851046691, 7.15539630189673, 7.1785454837637, 7.20117088328168, 
7.22329567956231, 7.24494154633701, 7.26612877955645, 7.2868764117507, 
7.30720231476474, 7.32712329225929, 7.34665516317654, 7.36581283720947, 
7.38461038317697, 7.40306109109009, 7.42117752859539, 7.43897159239586, 
7.45645455517621, 7.47363710849621, 7.49052940206071, 7.50714107972761, 
7.5234813125735, 7.53955882930103, 7.55538194424027, 7.57095858316901, 
7.58629630715272, 7.60140233458373, 7.61628356158038, 7.63094658089046, 
7.64539769942863, 7.65964295456468, 7.67368812926773, 7.68753876620163, 
7.70120018085745, 7.71467747380093, 7.72797554210556, 7.74109909003537, 
7.75405263903576, 7.76684053708551, 7.77946696745832, 7.79193595693806, 
7.80425138352811, 7.8164169836918, 7.82843635915759, 7.84031298332016, 
7.85205020726589, 7.86365126544865, 7.87511928104029, 7.88645727097769, 
7.89766815072691, 7.90875473878325, 7.91971976092457, 7.93056585423396, 
7.94129557090653, 7.95191138185419, 7.96241568012106, 7.9728107841214, 
7.98309894071089, 7.99328232810159, 8.00336305862995, 8.01334318138667, 
8.02322468471667, 8.03300949859667, 8.04269949689764, 8.05229649953865, 
8.06180227453835, 8.07121853996986, 8.0805469658245, 8.08978917578932, 
8.09894674894334, 8.10802122137675, 8.11701408773731, 8.12592680270789, 
8.13476078241865, 8.14351740579748, 8.15219801586179, 8.16080392095467, 
8.16933639592839, 8.17779668327778, 8.18618599422608, 8.19450550976564, 
8.20275638165564, 8.21093973337902, 8.2190566610606, 8.22710823434815, 
8.23509549725836, 8.24301946898925, 8.25088114470065, 8.25868149626424, 
8.26642147298455, 8.27410200229233, 8.28172399041139, 8.28928832300032, 
8.29679586577005, 8.30424746507847, 8.31164394850298, 1.38629436111989, 
3.52636052461616, 4.15888308335967, 4.54329478227, 4.82028156560504, 
5.03695260241363, 5.21493575760899, 5.36597601502185, 5.4971682252932, 
5.61312810638807, 5.71702770140622, 5.8111409929767, 5.89715386763674, 
5.97635090929793, 6.04973345523196, 6.11809719804135, 6.18208490671663, 
6.24222326545517, 6.29894924685594, 6.35262939631957, 6.40357419793482, 
6.45204895443723, 6.49828214947643, 6.5424719605068, 6.58479139238572, 
6.62539236800796, 6.66440902035041, 6.70196036600254, 6.73815249459596, 
6.77308037565554, 6.80682936039218, 6.83947643822884, 6.87109129461055, 
6.90173720665657, 6.93147180559945, 6.96034772910131, 6.98841318199959, 
7.01571242048723, 7.04228617193974, 7.06817200038804, 7.09340462586877, 
7.11801620446533, 7.1420365747068, 7.16549347506085, 7.18841273649695, 
7.21081845347222, 7.23273313617761, 7.25417784645652, 7.27517231945277, 
7.29573507274928, 7.31588350450979, 7.3356339819272, 7.35500192110526, 
7.37400185935016, 7.39264752072162, 7.41095187558364, 7.42892719480227, 
7.44658509915773, 7.46393660446893, 7.48099216286952, 7.49776170062257, 
7.51425465281641, 7.53047999524554, 7.54644627374602, 7.56216163122565, 
7.57763383260273, 7.59287028784482, 7.60787807327851, 7.6226639513236, 
7.63723438878947, 7.6515955738576, 7.6657534318617, 7.67971363996637, 
7.69348164083518, 7.70706265537047, 7.72046169459972, 7.7336835707759, 
7.74673290775362, 7.7596141506969, 7.77233157516961, 7.7848892956551, 
7.79729127354747, 7.80954132465341, 7.82164312623998, 7.8336002236611, 
7.84541603659248, 7.85709386490249, 7.86863689418417, 7.88004820097158, 
7.89133075766189, 7.90248743716286, 7.91352101728389, 7.92443418488756, 
7.93522953981691, 7.94590959861313, 7.95647679803678, 7.96693349840484, 
7.97728198675515, 7.98752447984877, 7.9976631270201, 8.00770001288403, 
8.01763715990848, 8.02747653086048, 8.03722003113301, 8.04686951095958, 
8.05642676752298, 8.06589354696427, 8.07527154629746, 8.0845624152353, 
8.09376775793108, 8.10288913464087, 8.11192806331074, 8.12088602109284, 
8.12976444579417, 8.13856473726163, 8.14728825870662, 8.15593633797239, 
8.16451026874704, 8.17301131172497, 8.18144069571937, 8.18979961872823, 
8.19808924895612, 8.20631072579402, 8.21446516075919, 8.22255363839696, 
8.23057721714645, 8.23853693017177, 8.24643378616036, 8.25426877009018, 
8.26204284396694, 8.26975694753298, 8.277411998949, 8.28500889544988, 
8.29254851397576, 8.30003171177957, 8.30745932701195, 8.31483217928456, 
8.3221510702129, 8.32941678393932, 8.33663008763715, 8.34379173199684, 
8.35090245169481, 8.35796296584568, 8.36497397843873, 8.3719361787591, 
8.37885024179449, 8.38571682862785, 8.39253658681668, 8.39931015075952, 
8.40603814205008, 8.41272116981953, 8.41935983106747, 8.42595471098197
)), row.names = c(NA, 289L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You may attract good answers if you share some data for sake of reproducibility, read [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Hi Dave2e, That did not work, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Hi jay.sf, I'm adding some data now, hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: @OpenSauce Nice. What is `p` though, did you forgot to add the `ggplot` code?

Comment: @jay.sf I didn't include it because it included my dataframe which wouldn't make sense. Here it is, cheers! `p<-ggplot(surscript,aes(x=t,y=q,group=sim))+geom_line()+
  ggtitle("1000 simulations of the prevalence of a pathogen (q) over time (t)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a couple of issues with the the definition for the plot.
One since the group factor did not apply to all of the `geom_line()` or is redefined, it should be moved from the ggplot function to the specific `geom_line()` definition.

Also, since you were adding in a new data frame to the definition, then explicitly add the "data=" to function.

Also, based on your model: `lm(surscript$logq~surscript$logt)` the equation for "temp" was incorrect it should be: `q_predicted =exp(-14.273)*(t^1.717)`.  If you truly want y=b*a^t, then your models should be: `lm(surscript$logq~surscript$t)` and q_predicted = exp(intercept)*exp(slope)^t.

```
library(ggplot2)

expmodint<- exp(-14.273)
expmodgrowth<- (1.717)
#q=exp(-14.273)*(t^1.717)
temp<-expmodint*(surscript$t^expmodgrowth)

temp1<-data.frame(temp,surscript$t)
head(temp1)  #notice the name change

ggplot(surscript, aes(x=t, y=q)) + 
   geom_line(aes(group=sim)) +
   geom_line(data=temp1, aes(x=surscript.t, y=temp), color="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I just added a y lim of 1 to the curve, went with `lm(surscript$logq~surscript$t)` and voila! I was a bit confused about where my equation was wrong but I think I understand now. Very well explained, thank you! I am still just a little uncertain about if I am using y=b x a^t or y=b x a^kt.

Comment: To save yourself the getting algebra correct, look into using the `predict()` function to perform the calculation.  One can perform the transformations within the `lm` function call and then `predict` take the model and a dataframe to calculation the prediction.

Comment: I am trying to get the mean estimate of the simulations when I use the `lm` function, have I done this correctly?

Comment: Yes, the reported coefficients is the best fit is on the entire vector passed to the lm function.